# Ubuntu does not boot - not even from live cd

Tags: boot, login, live-usb

I have Ubuntu installed on my second partition.

I wanted to copy a folder and I got told `ls` is an unknown command. So I tried to restart but it doesn't boot anymore. Just a console login appears but I cannot login there. If I boot from Ubuntu live USB stick it either doesn't start at all or the login screen appears and after entering Ubuntu I get back to the login. I want to repair the system but don´t know how.

(Dual boot from GRUB : Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit)

Comment: Give me a picture and mode you installed with, as well as system specs. (You could have accidently installed the wrong mode, which can be BIOS or EFI, or you could be under specs. A picture would help even more.)

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Comment: I should say it worked for 3 weeks before this happened. When I start it automatically goes to the recovery mode and there is the login loop. With BIOS or EFI would it work for 3 weeks if I installed wrong? Specs are: MSI Laptop GE Series GE60 Intel Core i7 3630QM (2.40 GHz) 8 GB Memory 1 TB HDD NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 15.6". I´m at work so I can sent a picture when I´m home :)